# transfer click event from one page to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to transfer click event from a page to another page using javascript. I have a div with a click event on page A and this is the div

**HTML:**

```
<div class="play">Play Sound</div>
<div class="pause">Stop Sound</div>
```

Then on page `B` I have a script file intended to receive the click of the div from page `A`. Is there a way how can I make it in such a way that if I click the div on page `A` let the script event on page `B` be called within the same application

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
       audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio.mp3');
       audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
       // audioElement.load()

   $.get();

   audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
       audioElement.play();
   }, true);

   $('.play').click(function() {
       audioElement.play();
   });

   $('.pause').click(function() {
      audioElement.pause();
   });
});
```

Comment: How could this possibly work?  Does clicking one of the div's navigate the user to page B?  Or are you expecting both pages to be open at the same time and talk to each other?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that both pages are open at thesame time and to talk to each other

Comment: No, not possible the way you are asking.  HTML is stateless and client side.  So one page does not know about another without using cookies or a database on the server.

Comment: Beautiful, Can I use cookies to achieve this

Comment: For what you have asked, not really.  Yes you can use cookies to pass data between pages, but it is not asynchronous.  Meaning that second page that you want to play the audio, will not know about the cookie being changed until it is reloaded.

Comment: No I dont want page reload.....

Comment: Then no, you cannot do this.  Your best bet, would be to use AJAX to update a database when the page A div is clicked, then on page B, use AJAX to poll that database every N seconds to see if it has changed.  Very dirty, but it would work.

Comment: Lengthy algorithm I see : )

Comment: Good news, you can do this ! I'll provide an answer how in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use socket or local storage. local storage fires an event when other tabs makes changes. check this answer [Javascript; communication between tabs/windows with same origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384)

Answer (score 0):

To transfer a click event from a page to another page using JavaScript you can use a shared worker (used in my answer) or a service worker. A shared worker is a program that runs in the background and can communicate with different pages. It is shared between pages.

The requirement to use a shared worker are; it must be served from a secure connection (https or localhost), and the target browser must support the shared worker APIs

An example to solve your problem:

a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Page A</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page A with controls</h1>

    <button id="play">Play Sound</button>
    <button id="pause">Stop Sound</button>
    <a href="b.html" target="_blank">Open page B</a>

  </body>
  <script src="a.js"></script>
</html>
```

a.js

```
(function () {
    const ME = "A";
    if (!window.SharedWorker) {
        console.log("window.SharedWorker not available");
        return;
    }
    const playButtonElement = document.getElementById("play");
    const pauseButtonElement = document.getElementById("pause");

    const sharedWorker = new SharedWorker("sharedworker.js", "audio");

    playButtonElement.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        sharedWorker.port.postMessage({
            from: ME,
            play: true
        });
    }, false);

    pauseButtonElement.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        sharedWorker.port.postMessage({
            from: ME,
            play: false
        });
    }, false);

    sharedWorker.port.onmessage = function(event) {
        ;//do nothing here
    };

    sharedWorker.port.start();

    sharedWorker.port.postMessage({
        from: ME,
        start: true
    });
}());
```

b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Page B</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page B with audio element</h1>

  </body>

  <script src="b.js"></script>
</html>
```

b.js

```
(function () {
    const ME = "B";
    if (!window.SharedWorker) {
        console.log("window.SharedWorker not available");
        return;
    }

    const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    // audioElement.load()
    document.body.appendChild(audioElement); // useful ?


    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
    }, true);


    const sharedWorker = new SharedWorker("sharedworker.js", "audio");
    sharedWorker.port.onmessage = function(event) {
        const messageObject = event.data
        console.log("received", messageObject);
        if (messageObject.hasOwnProperty("play")) {
            if (messageObject.play) {
                audioElement.play();
            } else {
                audioElement.pause();
            }
        }
    };

    sharedWorker.port.start();

    sharedWorker.port.postMessage({
        from: ME,
        start: true
    });
}());
```

sharedworker.js

```
//sharedworker.js
/*assuming we open page  a first, page b second*/
const A = "A";
const B = "B";

let portA;
let portB;
self.addEventListener("connect", function(connectEvent) {

    const port = connectEvent.ports[0];
    port.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        const data = event.data;
        if (data.start) {
            if (data.from === A) {
                portA = port;
            } else {
                portB = port;
            }
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            portB.postMessage(data);//relay message
        }
        console.log(`Shared worker memory report
portA, portB: ${portA}, ${portB}`);
    });

   port.start();

}, false);
```

**Not provided here, but needed to try the example**: A server program to serve static files, audio.mp3

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker